# Setting custom date formats through Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder causing request processing to continue after exception

Tags: spring-mvc, mockmvc

I have a MockMvc test for testing that a JSON payload to a controller is validated and a HTTP 400 (bad request) is rendered for `org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException` and `org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException`.

The respective exception handlers are implemented as follows.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class LocalExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(PropertyReferenceException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handlePropertyReferenceException(PropertyReferenceException ex) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(ex.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageConversionException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpMessageConversionException(HttpMessageConversionException ex) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(ex.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

I'm using a Spock specification for implementing the test. The setup is as follows.

```
MockMvc mvc

public JsonSerializer[] buildJsonSerializers() {
    return new JsonSerializer[]{new LocalDateSerializer(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_FORMAT)),
        new LocalDateTimeSerializer(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_TIME_FORMAT))};
}
Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer jsonCustomizer() {
    return builder -> {
        builder.simpleDateFormat(DATE_TIME_FORMAT);
        builder.serializers(buildJsonSerializers());
    };
}    
protected ObjectMapper buildObjectMapper() {
    def objectMapperBuilder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder()
    jsonCustomizer().customize(objectMapperBuilder)
    objectMapperBuilder.modules(new MoneyModule()
        .withMonetaryAmount(Money::of)
        .withAmountFieldName("number")
        .withFormattedFieldName("pretty"))
    objectMapperBuilder.build()
}

def setup() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = buildObjectMapper()

    def mockMvcBuilder = MockMvcBuilders
        .standaloneSetup(controller)
        .setControllerAdvice(LocalExceptionHandler.class)
        .setMessageConverters([new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(mapper)]
            .toArray(new HttpMessageConverter[1]))
        .setCustomArgumentResolvers(new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver())

        mvc = mockMvcBuilder.build()
}
```

So the above setup just sets the date format through a customizer and then builds the object mapper using the `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder`.

The problem with that setup is that the builder is causing an object mapper configuration that results in a weird MockMvc behaviour.

When posting a bad request to a controller, a proper Exception is thrown and handled by one of the above exception handlers but request processing is not stopped and the controller method is invoked.
When running the production code (as Spring Boot application) error handling is just fine resulting with a HTTP 400.

Just by removing the builder and mimicking just the configuration desired for the test (which is a proper date time format) the test works as expected and request processing is stopped after exception handling.

So basically instead of using the builder I do

```
def mapper = new ObjectMapper()
mapper.registerModule(new MoneyModule()
        .withMonetaryAmount(Money::of)
        .withAmountFieldName("number")
        .withFormattedFieldName("pretty"))

SimpleModule serializerModule = new SimpleModule()
        Arrays.asList(buildJsonSerializers())
            .forEach({ s -> serializerModule.addSerializer(s.handledType(), s) })
mapper.registerModule(serializerModule)
```

So it really looks like the builder is adding some configuration that MockMvc doesn't really deal with properly.
Would appreciate hints on resolving this.